# phpunit Laravel setup

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, chmod

I'm having problems with phpunit in my Laravel project. I cannot run it. I think is because the permissions are not set properly.

I'm trying to run it from my vendor directory:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

But, I got a command not found prompt in the terminal. Then, I checked the permissions and they look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--@ phpunit
```

Then, I changed to:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ phpunit
```

But, now, I have a permission denied prompt, even if I run the command with the sudo command.

Then, I saw that the psysh has these extra options:

```
lrwxr-xr-x psysh -> ../psy/psysh/bin/psysh
```

I guess that could be my issue but, I don't know what that 'l' option means, and that path that is 'linked' to that file. I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this and explain me what that 'l' means and how it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The „l“ in the file permissions marks a symbolic link. A symbolic link simply points to another file somewhere. The path you see if you use ls is the path to the real file.
As for the other problem: i do not know from the top of my head, but i believe there must be a binary-file within the phpunit-folder in the vendor files. Maybe try to call that direct?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in regard to the linked file. Do you know how can I set a link to that file, I guess the .php file inside the vendor directory is the one I need to execute to run the phpunit, so, I'd like to link it the executable to check if that's my issue

Comment: I've tried using chmod but, looks like is not the way to go.

Comment: To create a new symlink you can try `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`. But if the file is executable `chmod +x filename` you should be able to execute it with `./path/to/filename`. Do not forget the `./` in front of the path.

Comment: Ok, I'll try some stuff with the information you gave me and see if I can make it work correctly. Ty.